# Rails/Sinatra gem for time alerts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I have a web app which is suppose to allow users to set timers and it will notify them (via push notification) when the time is up. The user can also cancel these timers at any time.

Is there a gem that already does this? I need it to be able to dynamically assign a time and pass in a block on what to do at that time. Also, it's very important that I have the ability to cancel a particular block from executing.

Comment: You could use something such as: `https://github.com/resque/resque` where each timer is a `job` placed in the queue. The workers could then only removed the job from queue when the time's up.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`timers`](http://rubygems.org/gems/timers) gem.

Create a new timer group with Timers.new:

```
require 'timers'
timers = Timers.new
```

Schedule a proc to run after 5 seconds with Timers#after:

```
five_second_timer = timers.after(5) { puts "Take five" }
```

The `five_second_timer` variable is now bound to a `Timers::Timer` object. To cancel a timer, use `Timers::Timer#cancel`

For more check the README here:
https://github.com/celluloid/timers

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how I can keep track of a timer between web requests? For example user asks to start a timer, and 5 minutes later asks to stop it. How do i reference to the timer that was created to stop it?